# SQL query in php webpage runs very slow in displaying 30,000 entries

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database with about 30,000 rows that I would like to display in a webpage. Unfortunately it takes a very long time to fetch the data and freezes the browser multiple times during this operation. How can I speed this up?

```
<?php require_once'includes/session.php'; ?>
<?php require_once'includes/db_connect.php'; ?>
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "50";
?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">

    <title> Real Time Eelection Results</title>


         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css-table.css">

         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/style-table.js"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

</head>


<body>


                <form action="search.php" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="sql" />
                 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>





                    <?php 

                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_db"
                       ;


                      if($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){


                           echo "<table>";

                                echo "<thead>";

                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>ID</th>";
                                echo "<th>DATE</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 1    </th>";
                                  echo "<th>Data 2  </th>";
                                    echo "<th>Data 3</th>";
                                      echo "<th>Data 4  </th>";

                                echo "<th>Data 5</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 6</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 7 </th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 8</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 9</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 10</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 11</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 12</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 13</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 14</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 15</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 16</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 17</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 18</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 19</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 20</th>";
                                echo "<th>Data 21</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";

                                  echo "</thead>";

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                              echo "<tr>";
                              echo "<td><b>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                              echo "<td><b>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";

                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_1'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_2'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_3'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_4'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_5'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_6'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_7'] . "</td>";
                                 echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_8'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_9'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_10'] . "</td>";
                                 echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_11'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_12'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_13'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_14'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_15'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_16'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_17'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_18'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_19'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td><b>" . $row['data_20'] . "</td>";

                                  $pink = $row['data_21'];

               echo "<td><b><a href =".$pink.'.jpg'.">Image</a></td>";


                              echo "</tr>";
                              }

                              echo "</table>";


                            // Close result set
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                                  } else{
                             echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                            }
                            } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($connection);
                                }

                            // Close connection
                            mysqli_close($connection);

                            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't show 30,000 records? Use pagination / filtering / etc.

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example? I am new to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because you have to expect fetching and displaying 30,000 records to be slow. Specially if each of those rows have 21 columns in them.

Comment: @Todd: the basis of pagination in MySQL is `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE conditions LIMIT 0, 20`, where you change the `0` to `20`, `40`, etc. That is the starting number, and the second parameter is fixed at 20, which is how many records you want.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers will freeze because they are trying to render the page while it loads.  I ran into similar problems trying to modify large tables. The solution which worked best for me was to force the browser to render the entire table at once.  What you can try is putting the table in a hidden div and display the div once the page is loaded.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById("table-container").style.display = "block";
}; 
</script>
<div id="table-container" style="display: none;">
 ... table code here ...
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this just for desperation, I can't believe it actually worked (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination, that's the way to solve the problem.

Alternatively, if you are new to php, you can google out lot of pagination examples.

Some are here

http://phpflow.com/php/simple-tutorial-of-pagination-in-php/

http://phpflow.com/php/simple-pagination-with-php-and-mysql-using-jquery/